# Reduce number of third party asynchronous call from client

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webclient

I have an application in which the client sends multiple asynchronous javascripts requests to the third party servers. The problem which I am facing is that whenever the client responds to these responses the site becomes inactive for that miliseconds period of time. So sending these multiple requests increases the inactive time. For example if I send x requests and lets assume for each reponse that site becomes inactive for y avg miliseconds and then total inefficient time is x*y. How can I reduce these calls into one call. Third party which I am referring are like calls for google analytics , google ad leads and many more

Here is the example of one of the calls I am making

```
function () {
      var oldonload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function(){
      __adroll_loaded=true;
      var scr = document.createElement("script");
      var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
      scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
      scr.type = "text/javascript";
      scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
      ((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
      document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
      if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
      }());
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hanging"? What kind of blocking operations do they do? Rather file a bug for that third party to remove this behaviour, than try to influence its execution.

Comment: handing should have been edited with inactive . . means user cannot perform any action during this period

Comment: Don't you think that by bundling the requests the responses are getting larger as well, and the site will hang less often but longer on average? What exactly do these requests do, and what could be bundled to lower the overhead?

Comment: I know what "hanging" means, but what does *happen* when they hang? Which processing, which code does cause the app to hang?

Comment: https://github.com/chriso/chain.js this is what I could find best !! The requests will be processed parallely by this java script

Comment: Well, that microframework only helps to avoid some syntax boilerplate, but you'd need to understand the underlying basics anyway (it doesn't perform any parallelisation magic). Show us the offending code (which causes the app to hang), or we won't be able to help you!

Comment: You can check this http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140822_MJ_Z1Y/1/details/ . . the yellow marked api calls are area of concern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60748/discussion-between-learningbasics-android-and-bergi).

Comment: This is way too broad and we can't help you if you don't show us more specific code.

Comment: I have edited my code to include one example of asyc call which we are makng !! Please have a look

Comment: you can try delaying their injection for a few hundred ms between each one. this way, two hits will be less likely to land back-to-back and cause a noticeable pause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: inline async javascript does not block browser. But immediately invoked function does. You don't need to nest `window.onload` callback into the immediately invoked function.

I recommend you to provide one function doing all things in reaction to browser event. As an example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //do everything here
}
```

If it is possible by your app logic put this script right before `</body>` closing tag.

This might help you. Anyway I also recommend you to measure what your app really doing when script executes. You can do this easily, for example, with chrome developer tools (timeline tab).

Comment: The immediately invoked function in this case isn't blocking, it's just setting the window.onload. The outer function wrapper is only there to limit the scope. If the var statement for oldonload were not contained in a function, it would be a dangling global.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with how adroll is hijacking the window.onload, which fires after all page rendering is done. If I were you, I'd use jQuery (one of the other things you're calling already likely is, so get it from the Google URL so you only have to download it once). Put it right at the top of your HEAD tag, so that it downloads and loads first, and for YOUR code, use a $(document).ready() call, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html language="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webapp</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--// other library scripts go here -->
```

... the rest of the HEAD and BODY

```
    <!--// other paste-in tracking code scripts like Google Analytics go here-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(new function () {

            //Your onload code, which should no longer be blocked

        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> //followed by your adroll script
    (function () {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function(){
       __adroll_loaded=true;
       var scr = document.createElement("script");
       var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
       scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
       scr.type = "text/javascript";
       scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
       ((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
      document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
       if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
    }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way the scripts will download quietly in the background, and your code can go on and do what it needs to do without them. If it's really the scripts that are blocking your code for running, you can set a timeout function to delay it from loading for half a second or so while your code loads, by changing it like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> //followed by your adroll script
    (function () {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function(){
           setTimeout(function () {
               __adroll_loaded=true;
               var scr = document.createElement("script");
               var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" :
                 "http://a.adroll.com");
               scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
               scr.type = "text/javascript";
               scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
               ((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] || 
                 document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
           }, 500);
           if(oldonload){oldonload()}
       };
    }());
    </script>
```

This way, it immediately goes on to do whatever window.onload was supposed to do for your own code, and half a second later, the adroll code will execute asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

To actually reduce number of js requests you  can use bundling on the server. This will allow you to have single request to the server which will grab all necessary js-files and put them in a single response body.
So instead of doing something like this:

```
<script src='https://s.adroll.com/js/javascrpt1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://s.adroll.com/js/javascrpt2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
....
<script src='https://s.adroll.com/js/javascrpt100.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

You can make only one call

```
<script src='https://yourdomain/getAllJs' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

You can also implement it in a way that will be more reusable, for example you can pass filenames  of the scripts you need on certain page.

```
<script src='https://yourdomain/getjs?file=javascript1.js&file=javascript2.js&....file=javascript100.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I'm no sure what server technology you are using, so I didn't put an sample here. In ASP.NET for example you can use Bundling and Minification [out of the box](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Adroll is only supposed to make one call. He's talking about loading all of the different sets of code from one, I think, and to do what you're suggesting, he's going to need some kind of server-side script to download all the javascript files for him, or he's still making the same number of calls from the browser, he just has to make an EXTRA one to get the initial script that loads everything else.

Comment: @SteveK Not sure what limitation adroll has for js scripts,  but I'm pretty sure that you can cache js-files on the server on application start. And I actually tried to address OP's question of how to "Reduce number of third party asynchronous call from client"